# created() {} vs created: function() {}

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js

I've seen some people use

```
created: function() {
  // code
}
```

and also

```
created () {
  // code
}
```

and then a warning in the Vue docs to not do this

```
created: () => {
  // code
}
```

I understand that the first one is the usual way of writing functions, and the last one is the new es6 arrow functions which bind the 'this' keyword to scope. But what is the middle one? It looks like a mix of both. What're the implications of using that?

Comment: Middle one is probably from a javascript class https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes

Comment: Are you sure there's not a `function` before the second one, as in `function created () {
  // code
}`? As written, it's invalid syntax unless it's in a class (h/t @charlietfl, who pointed this out first).

Comment: @EdCottrell It's also valid in an object literal (like the first and third examples would be)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first and the second are identical. The second one just is a `ES6` syntax to defining function in the object.

```js
const obj1 = {
  name: 'Obj1',
  create() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
};

const obj2 = {
  name: 'Obj2',
  create: function() {
    console.log(this.name);
  }
};

obj1.create();
obj2.create();
```

Comment: that isn't es5 compatible

Comment: yes... to be honest i knew you could do that in new classes...didn't know it worked in object literals too

Comment: @charlietfl ES6 introduces a couple of useless syntactic sugars indeed (in my humble opinion).

Comment: @WaldemarIce I know this is hard to admit, but ES6 was not necessary :-P